# Etale sites for stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, simplicial-stuff, algebraic-stacks

Let $X$ be an algebraic stack, let $U\to X$ be a smooth cover by an algebraic space. In this setting, we have the big étale site of $X$ (if $X$ is a stack over a scheme $S$, this is the restriction of the big étale site of $S$ to $X$). We also have the Cech nerve $C(U/X)$, and the associated étale site. Are these two sites isomorphic? I.e. do abelian étale sheaves on the big étale site of $X$ correspond to abelian étale sheaves on $C(U/X)$, and do their cohomologies agree? Is there a reference where this is detailed?

So far, I only found Stacks Project Tag 06XJ, which gives a spectral sequence from the cohomology of the $C(U/X)_n$ to the cohomology of the big étale site of $X$, but this is not quite what I need.

Comment: I don't believe Cech cohomology computes etale cohomology, even in the case where $X$ is a scheme and $U\to X$ is an etale cover. I don't know an example or reference though.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think I am considering Cech cohomology here. I am not saying "apply $F$ to $C(U/X)$, turn this into a Cech complex, and compute cohomology", but I am considering the sheaf on the étale site of $C(U/X)$ and computing sheaf cohomology there (so this involves choosing an injective resolution of $F$).

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry, I think I misunderstood the question. I don't have anything substantial to say but in terms of modifying cech cohomology to compute derived cohomology, cohomological descent is interesting and useful (in case you haven't seen it before).